# C# / Dapper passing XML CLOB to Oracle stored procedure causes LPX-00210

Tags: oracle, .net-core, dapper, clob, xmltype

I am working on a bulk loading program that needs to load between 10K and 30K rows into multiple tables. The approach taken is to send in a large XML file to a stored procedure. This stored procedure does an INSERT/SELECT from XMLTABLE to load the table.

When the stored procedure is called from SQL Developer with the following XML, it runs fine:

```
<NMFC_CTL_STG>
<row><cust>CSA</cust><itemNbr>001010</itemNbr><sub>00</sub><seqNbr>0</seqNbr><status></status><effectiveDate>1995-08-26</effectiveDate><expirationDate></expirationDate></row>
</NMFC_CTL_STG>
```

When the C# client generates the above XML, saves it into a Unicode string that is placed into a Dapper OracleClob as a byte[], and then call the stored procedure, the following error happens:

C# code:

```
using var connection = InvocationHelper.GetConnection();
var parameters = new OracleDynamicParameters();
var clobData = new OracleClob(connection as OracleConnection);

clobData.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

parameters.Add("pi_nmfc_data", bytes, OracleDbType.Clob, ParameterDirection.Input);

connection.Execute(procedureName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Error

> Error: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
> ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 1
> LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'S'
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
> ORA-06512: at "RATES_PBLC.NMFC_IMPORTS", line 244
> ORA-06512: at line 1

Line 244 of RATES_PBLC.NMFC_IMPORTS is

```
l_nmfc_xml_blob := xmltype(pi_nmfc_data);
```

I simply cannot figure out the S it is finding. I did look at the binary array and saw that the first two bytes are 255,254, which is the Byte Order Mark (BOM).  I tried stripping that off and still got the same error. I tried changing the encoding to UTF-8 and the stored procedure didn't like that one bit. I did see something about the issue being the line breaks, so I removed those and still get the same error.

Any suggestions on what is going here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an `OracleClob` object, writing some data into it from a byte array `bytes`, and then using `bytes` as the value of the parameter in your call to `parameters.Add(...)`.

Did you perhaps mean to use `clobData` instead of `bytes` as the value of the parameter?

The error message you are getting is because the string `System.Byte[]` (i.e. what you get when you call `.ToString()` on a byte array) is being sent to the stored procedure.  I verified this by writing a stored procedure that called `raise_application_error` with the procedure parameter in the message, and this is what was in the error message.  Also, I can reproduce your error running `select xmltype('System.Byte[]') from dual` in SQL*Plus.

Incidentally, you don't show us how you created `bytes` in your app, but on my system I needed to create it using `Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16LE").GetBytes(...);`.  That may be an artefact of how my Oracle database (18c XE) is set up, though.

Comment: MAJOR PALM TO FACE!!!!!!!!!  Yep, ain't going to work well sending in a byte[] when it is expecting a OracleClob.  Thank you!